# Derivation of the Geodesic Equation

Tags: calculus, tensors

From page 40 of A. Schild and J. L. Synge's "Tensor Calculus", I'm having issues understanding the following mathematical steps ( I feel like it's simple algebra that I'm messing up. We have, $a_{rm}$ with varying Latin indices being the metric tensor and $p^{r} = \frac{dx^{r}}{dt}$ is the derivative of the coordinates w.r.t. the parameter $t$.

> $$a_{rm}\frac{dp^{m}}{dt}+\frac{ \partial a_{rm}}{\partial
>  x^{n}}p^{m}p^{n}-\frac{1}{2}\frac{\partial a_{mn}}{\partial
>  x^{r}}p^{m}p^{n}=0  $$ By a mere rearrangement of dummy suffices, we
>    have identically
>
> $$ \frac{ \partial a_{rm}}{\partial x^{n}}p^{m}p^{n} =
>  \frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{ \partial a_{rm}}{\partial x^{n}}+\frac{ \partial
>  a_{rn}}{\partial x^{m}}\right)p^{m}p^{n} $$

Probably going to get down voted for this, but I'd rather not press on confused.

Comment: Are you sure you have the indices right? I don't think the Einstein notation matches up. I also don't see why this would be worthy of a downvote. Edit: Is this useful to you? http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/522919/calculation-mistake-in-variation-of-length-functional

Comment: No to the related questions ( sadly ), but the indices are exactly as they are in the book. The next equation he came up with was $a_{rm} \frac{dp^{m}}{ds}+[mn,r]p^{m}p^{n}$ Where the bracketed term is the Christoffel symbol of the Second Kind.

Comment: You are aware of the fact that the second line is not a rearrangement of the first, but a statement on how to write the left hand side of the second line differently?

Comment: That certainly helps quite a bit. I didn't notice that ( I need more sleep...) But I'm still failing to grasp how those are equivalent. Does it have to do with writing a tensor as the sum of it's symmetric and antisymmetric parts?

Comment: The first and second line are not equivalent. The first line contains some terms which the author wants to write down differently. For this purpose he writes down an identity which applies to one of the terms in the first line (this is the second line).

Comment: By "those" I mean the LHS and the RHS of the second line. I feel like if one uses an identity for simplification it should be one that was at least mentioned prior. The rewriting of of a second order tensor--I should say--in terms of symmetric and antisymmetric parts is what this looks most similar to to me. Is there some other fundamental tensor identity I'm lacking?

Comment: It's easier to see what's happening in the last line if you go from right to left: Take the second term in the RHS, relabel its indices, and combine it with the first to get the LHS.

Comment: I see it. Switching the r with the m in the second term of the RHS would yield twice what's in the parentheses, but is this something that can always be done with any second order tensor?

Comment: I was under the impression that we could only relabel indices that were summed over?

Comment: $m,n$ are summed. Only $r$ is fixed.

Comment: Yup. That did it. $m,n$ appear as covariant in the metric and contra in the $p$. The result is a covariant vector correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Substituting line two into the first line, we have 
$$ a_{rm}\frac{dp^{m}}{dt}+\frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{ \partial a_{rm}}{\partial x^{n}}+\frac{ \partial
 a_{rn}}{\partial x^{m}}\right)p^{m}p^{n}-\frac{1}{2}\frac{\partial a_{mn}}{\partial x^{r}}p^{m}p^{n}=0 
$$

After a little bit of factoring and rewriting the first term we get:

$$ a_{rm}\frac{d^{2}x^{m}}{dt^{2}} + \frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{ \partial a_{rm}}{\partial x^{n}}+\frac{ \partial
 a_{rn}}{\partial x^{m}} - \frac{\partial a_{mn}}{\partial x^{r}} \right)\frac{dx^{m}}{dt}\frac{dx^{n}}{dt} $$

Noticing the bracketed term with the factor of one half is the Christoffel symbol of the first kind:

$$ a_{rm}\frac{d^{2}x^{m}}{dt^{2}}+[mn,r]\frac{dx^{m}}{dt}\frac{dx^{n}}{dt}=0  $$

Multiplying through by $ a^{rs} $:

$$ \delta^{s}_{m}\frac{d^{2}x^{m}}{dt^{2}} + a^{rs}[mn,r]\frac{dx^{m}}{dt}\frac{dx^{n}}{dt}=0 $$

In the second term we have the Christoffel symbol of the second kind, $\Gamma^{s}_{mn} $ which leads us to:

$$ \frac{d^{2}x^{s}}{dt^{2}} + \Gamma^{s}_{mn}\frac{dx^{m}}{dt}\frac{dx^{n}}{dt}=0 $$

the Geodesic Equation!